# What charset detector for unknown webpage encoding can be used in C++ application?

Tags: c++, qt, character-encoding

I use C++, Qt 4.8.5, Visual Studio 2010. I'd like to create Windows GUI application which downloads some web pages. Note that my program is built in 32 bit mode and should be run in 32 and 64 bit Windows environment. I don't need to use Qt webkit. I need to analyze web pages. But the problem is character encoding. What charset auto-detection C/C++ library can be used in the case of absent charset information? MLang can't be used, because it is COM based. Extreme accuracy of detection is not required. I will prefer simple API and simple Windows friendly build instructions.

Comment: You probably need to use some HTTP client library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) and to learn a lot more about the [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) protocol, notably [response headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers#Responses)

Comment: HTTP and HTML have some fields describing the encoding. Do you also want to deal with cases where they are incorrect?

Comment: Also, please give the expected input and output, and what you have tried, so what the actual output is.

Comment: "Extreme accuracy" implies that a correct solution exists. That may be a stretch.

Comment: I mean that HTTP and HTML sometimes don't offer encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is no information about the encoding, the only way is to convert the data using many encodings and choose the best result. Evaluation of the result depends on your goal. For example, this function tries to choose between CP1251 and UTF-8 encodings assuming that the data represents text in Russian:

```
QString detect_encoding(const QByteArray &array) {
  QString alphabet = QString::fromUtf8("АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя");
  QString try_utf = QString::fromUtf8(array);
  QString try_win = QTextCodec::codecForName("cp1251")->
    toUnicode(try_utf.toLatin1());
  int count_utf = 0, count_win = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < try_utf.length(); i++) {
    if (alphabet.contains(try_utf[i])) {
      count_utf++;
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < try_win.length(); i++) {
    if (alphabet.contains(try_win[i])) {
      count_win++;
    }
  }
  if (count_win > count_utf) {
    return try_win;
  } else {
    return try_utf;
  }
}
```

There are quite few encodings that can represent Russian. You only need to add them to the comparation. The same approach should work for any language or combination of several languages, you just need to change the alphabet setting and encodings. (I advise to refactor this function. In current state it's just an illustration rather than a piece of production code.)

When there is no specific target language, decoding data without information about encoding is hardly possible. Also arbitrary page can contain some special symbols that can confuse detector. There is no universal way. I wish every site used UTF-8.